# Does every thread have its main function?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, program-entry-point

Does every thread have its own main function?

I know that its have its own stack, but what about main function (not necessarily a function which called main).

For example, when creating a thread, we pass a function as an argument for the new thread to run it.

I tried to search about this topic, but couldn't find answers.

Comment: Threads are there to run things in parallel. What else would you pass if not a piece of code for it to run? what programming language are you using?

Comment: @TonyTannous So every thread has its own main function which he executes?

Comment: Main is the entry point of a program. Its where execution starts. If you want to think about the passed function as "main" of that thread then so be it.

Comment: What do you mean, "its _own?_" Are you asking whether each thread must have its own _unique_ main function? That's not true in any programming language or environment that I've ever heard of. You can have any number of threads that all start by calling the _same_ main function.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63121642/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128760/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Quote from this [article](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Epxk/416/notes/05-threads.html):

> In a multi-threaded process, all of the process’ threads share the same memory and open files. Within the shared memory, each thread gets its own stack. Each thread has its own **`instruction pointer`** and registers. Since the memory is shared, it is important to note that there is no memory protection among the threads in a process.

Therefore, the «main» function could be called the function with which the execution of the thread begins, i.e. the address of the first instruction of which is initially loaded into the `instruction pointer`. It is worth noting that the first code that is executed in a thread can be a routine in the standard library that initializes and then calls a user-supplied function, which in this case can be called the «main».
But this is not a common term, it is usually called simply, a `thread function`.

However, there is a concept, the `main thread`. This is the first thread that is executed when the program (process) starts.